# Find and replace full words only?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm completely new to Python and I'm currently trying to write a smalle script for finding&replacing different inputs in all files of the same type in a folder. It currently looks like this and works so far:

```
import glob
import os

z = input('filetype? (i.e. *.txt): ')
x = input('search for?: ')
y = input('replace with?: ')

replacements = {x:y}
lines = []

for filename in glob.glob(z):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
         for line in infile:
            for src, target in replacements.items():
                line = line.replace(src, target)
            lines.append(line)

    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line)
            lines = []
```

My problem is that I want to replace full words only, so when trying to replace '0' with 'x', '4025' should not become '4x25'. I've tried to incorporate regex, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please provide reproducible code which somebody can run and try. Also what is the sample input and desired output? Not clear.

Comment: I would try to use regex e.g. with \b (word bounds). With regex you can describe your pattern the way you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
line.replace(src, target)
```

try

```
re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape(src) + r'\b', target, line)
```

after importing `re`. `\b` matches a *word boundary*.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is nearly it. I have one last problem: I often have to replace a NoDataValue of "-9999" with "0". With your solution it seems like "-9999" can not be found? EDIT: Or is this a problem with the input I'm using at the top and then inputting "-9999" when prompted?

Comment: @user16356396 I don't think `-9999` is considered a word in Python, so you'll have to find another approach. Using text replacements on integers seems very suspect regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex (`re`) and add `^` and `$` patterns in your expression.

`line = re.sub('^'+src+'$', target, line)`

Don't forget to `import re`.

Comment: This is wrong for multiple reasons. OP wishes to replace whole words, not entire lines. And if they try to replace a word with special regex characters in it stuff breaks too.